# uninitialized constant MyApp::Application::GeoKit (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

first off I'm running ruby 1.9.3-p448, and rails 4.0.3

Here's the passenger error I'm getting:

```
uninitialized constant MyApp::Application::GeoKit (NameError)
  /home/deployer/html/myapp/config/application.rb:12:in `<class:Application>'
```

And from application.rb

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'
require 'geokit'

Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env)

module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # line 12
    GeoKit::default_units = :miles
    # ...
```

I've verified that my Gemfile contains

```
gem 'geokit'
gem 'geokit-rails'
```

I've run bundle install, and the passenger error page shows both geokit, and geokit-rails under the Activated Ruby gems section:

> geokit => 1.8.4
>
> geokit-rails => 2.0.1

I'm quite new to ruby/rails, so if there are any other files I need to post, please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove this line from `application.rb` and put it in `config/initalizer/geo_ket.rb`

```
Geokit::default_units = :miles
```

it was happening because gems are loaded after `line` so it fails to recognise its class so it throws error.

Comment: I moved it to its own initializer file, and I'm still getting the same message, only now it's "uninitialized constant GeoKit (NameError)" geo_kit.rb:1. I've run bundle check, bundle update, bundle outdated, etc and I'm not seeing any errors there.

Comment: That doesn't seem to make a difference either. I removed the require 'geokit' from application.rb, tried it, nothing. I then added require 'geokit' to the initializer file, and still nothing. I removed the gem  (gem uninstall geokit-rails and geokit) and then reran bundle install, but that doesn't seem to be the issue either.

I commented out the geokit code in the initializer file, and in all my models using it, and the app itself is running fine. Is there a way to see if there is a conflict in the gem itself? It really seems to be related to Geokit itself

Comment: ok, i checked the source code of geokit and  found that it is called `Geokit` instead of `GeoKit` .

Comment: @DustinHansen since i spent some time in finding the error, i am very curious to know that does the above solution works for you ?

Comment: Let me try that really quick.

Comment: That was it, you're awesome. The weird thing is it was working with GeoKit just up until yesterday. Someone may have updated the bundle though, not sure. Anyway, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. 
Gem **geokit-rails3** depends on gem **geokit**.
I was having **geokit => 1.8.5**, downgrading it to **geokit => 1.6.5** did the trick.